# Paypal submit is not going giving any call-back

Tags: javascript, react-native, paypal

while making a submit in PayPal ACDC, I'm not getting any callback, neither in then nor in catch:

```
if (paypal.HostedFields.isEligible()) {
                    // Renders card fields
                    paypal.HostedFields.render({
                        // Call your server to set up the transaction
                        createOrder: function () {
                            return <order-id>;
                        },
                        styles: {
                            '.valid': {
                                'color': 'green'
                            },
                            '.invalid': {
                                'color': 'red'
                            },
                            'input': {
                                'box-sizing': 'border-box',
                                'width': '100%',
                                'height': '46px',
                                'margin-top': '8px',
                                'background': '#EBEBEB',
                                'border-radius': '6px',
                                'font-style': 'normal',
                                'font-weight': '400',
                                'font-size': '18px',
                                'line-height': '18px',
                                'color': '#333',
                                'padding-left': '10px',
                            },
                        },
                        fields: {
                            number: {
                                selector: "#card-number",
                                placeholder: "XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX",
                            },
                            cvv: {
                                selector: "#cvv",
                                placeholder: "XXX"
                            },
                            expirationDate: {
                                selector: "#expiration-date",
                                placeholder: "MM/YY"
                            }
                        }
                    }).then(function (cardFields) {
                        document.querySelector("#card-form").addEventListener('submit', (event) => {

                            event.preventDefault();

                            cardFields.submit({
                                // Cardholder's first and last name
                                cardholderName: document.getElementById('card-holder-name').value,
                                // Billing Address
                                billingAddress: {
                                    // Street address, line 1
                                    streetAddress: document.getElementById('card-billing-address-street').value,
                                    // Street address, line 2 (Ex: Unit, Apartment, etc.)
                                    extendedAddress: document.getElementById('card-billing-address-unit').value,
                                    // State
                                    region: document.getElementById('card-billing-address-state').value,
                                    // City
                                    locality: document.getElementById('card-billing-address-city').value,
                                    // Postal Code
                                    postalCode: document.getElementById('card-billing-address-zip').value,
                                    // Country Code
                                    countryCodeAlpha2: document.getElementById('card-billing-address-country').value
                                }
                            }).then(function () {
                                console.log("CHECKOUT_SUCESS")
                            }).catch(function (error) {
                                console.error("CHECKOUT_ERROR", error)
                            });
                        });
                    });
                } else {
                    // Hides card fields if the merchant isn't eligible
                    document.querySelector("#card-form").style = 'display: none';
                }
```

I'm facing problem when executing **cardFields.submit**, I'm not getting any callback from the **cardFields.submit** function.

**This is the exact error I'm getting after submitting:**

Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': Invalid target origin 'null' in a call to 'postMessage'.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem occurs when attempting to test hosted fields from a local file.

It requires an http(s) webserver.